# expand a dense matrix

Tags: fortran, fortran90

What would be the most efficient way to expand a dense matrix with new columns in FORTRAN?

Say T is a dense matrix m by n

and I would like to make it m by n+1.
One strategy I could think of : Reallocate at each step and assign the last column or would there be some better ways, such as allocating some space before and checking if that is sufficient and if not do the reallocation kind of stuff? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to translate some code from MATLAB (:,end+1)? In any case - short answer is - it isn't that effective. As a matter of fact, it is quite an expensive operation.

Comment: Exactly, I know that it is inefficient in MATLAB as well, such as a=[a v] so to expand a with vector v however I guess C++ vector structure seems like a better option at least to me now, to store the columns in a vector so that also do the operations with this as well.

Comment: If you want to do it, regardless, this would be one of the ways. http://www.archivum.info/comp.lang.fortran/2010-01/00050/Re-Some-matlab--gt-fortran-translation.html (better read the whole thread)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `m` and `n` are in some sense not exceedingly large, so that your matrices fit into memory and what you're after is performance in time, what I'd do I'd allocate a large matrix and store the actual size separately. This is what, for example, BLAS libraries use as a 'leading dimension'. Then, when you need to add a column, you check if your actual size is still smaller than the maximum size, and reallocate memory if necessary.

Comment: Have an example of this appoach maybe?

Comment: yes ok, this is what I was thinking also and I am guessing that this would be the most efficient way to do that

Comment: @Rook: in fact, I do. A couple of years ago I was working on a Monte Carlo code where an elementary update was to add/remove a row and a column to/from a matrix (Typical sizes of the matrices were several thousand.) Since it's an MC code, you just can't afford reallocating things on every step.

Comment: @Umut Tabak: BTW, depending on what you are going to do with these matrices, you may find useful a couple of facts from linear algebra. Look up the words Sherman-Morrison or Woodbury formulas, and/or check the 'sparse matrices' chapter in Numerical Recipes.

Comment: @Zhenya, what are the relation of these pointers to expanding the column size of a dense matrix? Anyway, using a C++ matrix library is a better choice for this, a vector would do the trick with allocation optimisation on STL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Fortran 2003 Compiler you might make use of move_alloc: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/fortran/lin/compiler_f/lref_for/source_files/rfmvallo.htm