# Add number and move it in the same Array in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I have the array in my code which consist of from 2049 the total number of the element. where 1681 is called fluid particles and 368 is called boundary particles.
where now the arrangement of particles 1681+368=2049.  I need to add 40 particles to my array. where the new particles must add after 1681.my question is, how can move the 368 from my array to add the new number which is 40 after 1681 to become the total number =2088.
note ,from time to time I must add the same number to my array

Comment: This is a pretty confused question, could you please try to use some proper text formatting and a more understandable explanation of what you are looking for? To me it sounds like you are looking for arrays that could grow dynamically?

Comment: Yes i want my array grow automatically  depend on my condition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7468268/1004168

Comment: you have a 1D array with dimensions (1:2049) and you want to increase that to (1:2088) and move elements (1682:2049) to (1721:2088).  Do I have that right?

Comment: Yes, correct and I have to put  elements in place of 1682 by new elements

Answer (score 2):

you need to allocate a new array and copy things over. Example:

```
 real, allocatable::a(:),tmp(:)
 allocate(a(4))
 a=(/1,2,3,4/)
 write(*,*)a
 allocate(tmp(5))
 tmp(1:2)=a(1:2)
 tmp(4:5)=a(3:4)
 tmp(3)=0
 call move_alloc(tmp,a)
 write(*,*)a
```

> 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
>
> 1.0 2.0 0.0 3.0 4.0

note if you really have a dusty old f95 compiler w/out `move_alloc` that last line needs to be replaced with:

```
 deallocate(a)
 allocate(a(5))
 a=tmp
 deallocate(tmp)
```

This probably takes twice as long as using `move_alloc` since it actually copies everything twice.  If you find yourself doing this with large arrays you really should upgrade the compiler.

Comment: There is also the much more concise `a=[a(:2), 0., a(3:)]`.

Comment: not w/f95 though. I'm guessing that's 2008 standard? (doesn't work with ifort 13, which is i think 2003 compliant)

Comment: Reallocation on assignment and the use of the square parentheses for array constructors are both Fortran 2003.  ifort requires /standard-semantics for this to work, and has had bugs where the thing being reassigned on the left hand side also appears in the array constructor.

Comment: It's F2003 (as is `move_alloc`).  ifort 13 wasn't F2003 compliant and even 15 refuses to compile some F2003 code.